# Detect the row and get the td value using javascript. (Dynamic table)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I totally want to avoid using inline javascript! But i have a table which is being dynamically generated from a mysql database using php. I want that if a user clicks on any of the rows it creates a modal with the information about the clicked row. Now i am able to initialise the modal, however the first column of the table holds an index value which can be used to retrieve the information about that row. My question is how can i retrieve that index value using javascript. To initiate the modal i am using the following code:

```
$('#production tr').click(function(){
     $('#review_order').modal('show');
}) ;
```

Table markup:

```
<table id="order_basket" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
       <th>Voucher ID</th>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th>Created By</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr><td>1<td>
        <td>Something here</td>
        <td>Some Person</td></tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Post a bit of our table's markup - include the code that has the index  value that you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you've added `rowspan`/`colspan` attributes, the first column in a row is the `tr`'s first `td` child:

```
$('#production tr').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).children("td").first().text();
    // `index` is the text in the first column in the clicked row

    $('#review_order').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: @Namit: Do note that your posted HTML is invalid because you actually don't have any `tr`s. The ID seems different as well but if it works then never mind :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i just wrote it quickly so that everyone could get an idea. Sorry!